# Driving series wound motor with MOSFETs

Tags: mosfet, dc-motor, h-bridge

I'm trying to control a series wound DC motor with PWM. The motor is rated for 23V and 0.35kW.

The motor has 4 connections which form 2 coils that have to be connected in series. To switch motor direction either of the two coils has to be reversed, but not both. This means some of my MOSFETs are going to be in between two loads and I have no idea if they should be N or P channel. One coil has a resistance of about 2.6 Ohms. The second coil measures about 0.5 Ohms. Together this doesn't add up to the rated power, but the motor is quite old and hasn't run in a while so the resistance might drop a little once it starts turning again and the brushes wear in.

Can I just pretend like the higher resistance coil is my load and only use N channel MOSFETs like this to control the second coil? (IRLZ44N is just a placeholder, I haven't picked any parts yet)
[image]

If so:
Will this cause issues with the MOSFETs not turning on fully and producing excess heat?
Where should I place flyback diodes?

I'm also not sure what will happen when the motor is coasting and it turns into a generator (across the higher resistance coil). I assume there should be a resistor somewhere to dissipate this power but again I have no idea where.

Comment: _"The motor is rated for 23V and 0.35kW... One coil has a resistance of about 2.6 Ohms. The second coil measures about 0.5 Ohms"_ - something doesn't add up here because 23V and 3.1 ohms equates to only 171W.

Comment: The motors are a few decades old and haven't run for a while, it wouldn't surprise me if the resistance drops back down a bit when the brushes wear in again. They're in a very old Toyota forklift that originally used mechanical switches and a huge power resistor.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please can you edit this new information into your Question. Otherwise, readers would have to read everything and piece the actual question together. (Please rewrite the question text as needed to contain this info, don't just drop it at the end under an 'EDIT' heading.) Thanks and, again, welcome.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited it in

Comment: How often are you going to switch? Would you consider a DPDT relay instead for simplicity?

Comment: I checked DPDT relays but all the ones I can find with a reasonable price usually have 10% of their current rating for the NC contacts. In that case, it seems like I have to end up using a lot of single throw relays which doesn't seem simpler to me